# Когда примитив преобразовался?

Tags: java, generics

Допустим я отправляю примитивы

```
   int a = 22;
   long b = 43L;
   byte c = 2;
   short d = 4;
   Classus.funcius(a,b,c,d);
```

в клacc `Classus`, но при стирании типов оказалось что мои примитивы уже классы.
Как и когда прошло преобразование и можно ли об этом где-то почитать

```
class Classus{
 public static <T> void funcius(T... arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    System.out.println("This " + g[i].getClass());
   }}
```

Вывод

```
This class java.lang.Integer
This class java.lang.Long
This class java.lang.Byte
This class java.lang.Short
```

Comment: java autoboxing

Comment: Во спасибо, это я и искал!

Answer (score 0):

Вы используете параметризованный тип в аргументе метода, дженерики работают только с объектами. Когда вы подсовываете примитив, срабатывает врапер, а на выходе получаются объекты-обертки.

Comment: Это понятно, я просто хотел узнать как и почему это происходит. И уже узнал